# How to disable the onmousedown function using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:    <`td class="ewPointer" onmousedown="ew_Sort(event,'sampple.asp?order=brgy%5Fid&amp;ordertype=ASC',1);">`

I just want to disable the onmousedown function and replace it with my jquery function.

I used this code but didn't work.

```
$('.ewPointer').live('click',function(e) {e.preventDefault(); });
```

Is there a way?

Thanks

(I'm using that source page in my ajax function.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".ewPointer").removeAttr("onmousedown");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SZaw5/

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.ewPointer').removeAttr('onmousedown');
```